# Proving that the integral of $\cos^m(x)\sin{(nx)}$ between $0$ and $\pi$ is zero

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing

I've been doing a question that initially asks to derive a reduction formula for the indefinite integral of $\cos^m(x)\sin{(nx)}$ then the next part asks to prove that:

$$\int_0^\pi\cos^m(x)\sin{(nx)} \;\text{d}x=0$$ 
when $n$ and $m$ are both odd or both even.

The first way I did it was to use the reduction formula which seems to work (though it's not quite a neat as I'd like) but I had another thought as to a way to answer this, so I'm wondering whether this could be a correct approach:

---

If you take the integral and shift it by $\pi/2$ so that the limits become symmetric about $0$, or let $u=x-\pi/2$ so that:
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^m(u+\pi/2)\sin(n(u+\pi/2)) \; \text{d}u$$
then all it would take is for one to prove that:

$$   \cos^m(u+\pi/2)\sin(n(u+\pi/2))$$ is an odd function for for $n$, $m$ both odd or even. Or to show that:

$$  \cos^m((-u)+\pi/2)\sin(n((-u)+\pi/2)) \;\; \text{is equal to}\;\;  -\cos^m(u+\pi/2)\sin(n(u+\pi/2)) $$

---

Now, quite how you'd show that I'm not sure but I'm just wondering whether this would a correct  way show what the question asks?

Comment: You could try to prove that $\cos^m x \sin nx$ is antisymmetric about $\frac\pi2$ under the conditions you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a gross way using Euler's formula and the binomial theorem:

Let $I$ be the integral above.

\begin{eqnarray} 
I &=& \int_0^\pi {1 \over 2} (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^m {1 \over 2i} (e^{inx}-e^{-inx}) dx \\
&=& {1 \over 4i} \int_0^\pi (\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} e^{ikx} e^{-i(m-k)x} ) (e^{inx}-e^{-inx}) ) dx \\
&=& {1 \over 4i} \sum_{k=0}^m \int_0^\pi (e^{i (2k-m+n)x} - e^{i (2k-m-n)x})dx
\end{eqnarray}
Since $2k-m+n, 2k-m-n$ are even, we obtain the desired result.